# How to retain only alphabets from a string of words

Tags: python-3.x, string, split, cpu-word, isalpha

Below is my code to remove all numbers and special character from a string:

```
string = 'Date: 2008-01-04 18:08:50 -0500 (Fri, 04 Jan 2008)'
words = ""
for char in string:
    if char.isalpha():
        words += char
print(words)
```

The output I get is:

```
DateFriJan
```

The output I need:

```
Date Fri Jan
```

How can I split the string with the spaces included so these are separate words

Comment: `char.isalpha()` won't include space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
for char in string:
    if char.isalpha():
        words += char
        if not string[(string.index(char) + 1)].isalpha():
            words += " "
print(words)
```

You will get `Date Fri Jan`

Basicly it just check if the next char in the string is not alpha, then it will add a space to words